# how do I get a query to show double rows for every record?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a SELECT query of some sort which shows me 10 rows.

Is there a way I can change this query so that it shows each row twice, giving me 20 in total?

Furthermore, can some arbitrary identifier be added to the SELECT to allow distinguishing each pair of rows?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select a, b, c, 1 as pair from myTable
union all
select a, b, c, 2 as pair from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so with a `UNION ALL`. Just run.

```
<Your Query> 
UNION ALL
<Your Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @cdaiga's answer and include a unique identifier per row...

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT <your columns>, @i := @i + 1 as num from ...
UNION ALL
SELECT <your columns>, @i := @i + 1 as num from ...
```

Then you'll have a `num` column with a consecutive sequence number. Here's an example: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38ecd3/17).

Answer (score 0):

Select columns twice with arbitrary identifier then unpivot/convert to rows using union all

for example given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select fb_uid,id,username from users;
+--------+----+----------+
| fb_uid | id | username |
+--------+----+----------+
|      1 |  1 | John     |
|      2 |  2 | Jane     |
|      3 |  3 | Ali      |
|      6 |  6 | Bruce    |
|      7 |  7 | Martha   |
|      8 |  8 | Sidney   |
|     10 | 10 | charlie  |
|     12 | 12 | Elisa    |
|     14 | 14 | Samantha |
|     15 | 15 | Hannah   |
|     16 | 16 | Hannah   |
|     17 | 17 | Kevin    |
|     18 | 18 | Kevin    |
|     19 | 19 | Ruth     |
+--------+----+----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select fb_uid,id1 id,uname1 username
from
(
select fb_uid,id id1,username uname1, id id2, username uname2 from users u
) u1
union all
select fb_uid,id2,uname2
from
(select fb_uid,id id1,username uname1, id id2, username uname2 from users u
) u2
order by id
```

result

```
+--------+----+----------+
| fb_uid | id | username |
+--------+----+----------+
|      1 |  1 | John     |
|      1 |  1 | John     |
|      2 |  2 | Jane     |
|      2 |  2 | Jane     |
|      3 |  3 | Ali      |
|      3 |  3 | Ali      |
|      6 |  6 | Bruce    |
|      6 |  6 | Bruce    |
|      7 |  7 | Martha   |
|      7 |  7 | Martha   |
|      8 |  8 | Sidney   |
|      8 |  8 | Sidney   |
|     10 | 10 | charlie  |
|     10 | 10 | charlie  |
|     12 | 12 | Elisa    |
|     12 | 12 | Elisa    |
|     14 | 14 | Samantha |
|     14 | 14 | Samantha |
|     15 | 15 | Hannah   |
|     15 | 15 | Hannah   |
|     16 | 16 | Hannah   |
|     16 | 16 | Hannah   |
|     17 | 17 | Kevin    |
|     17 | 17 | Kevin    |
|     18 | 18 | Kevin    |
|     18 | 18 | Kevin    |
|     19 | 19 | Ruth     |
|     19 | 19 | Ruth     |
+--------+----+----------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```